# How to migrate a template from Handlebar to React's JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars.js

I need to migrate my code from backbone view to react view.

I am using Handlebars templates in the backbone view which I need to put in a React component's `render` method.

Can someone suggest how to move these two utility methods to JSX

1. with

   ```
   <div>
     {{#with paymentDescription}}
       <div class="test">
         <p>some text</p>
       </div>
     {{/with}}
   </div>
   ```
2. unless

   ```
   <div class="name">
     {{ abc.def.firstName }} {{ abc.def.lastName }}
     {{#unless quote.def}}
       &nbsp;
     {{/unless}}
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Post code as formatted text not as an image! I've edited for you. As for the question, you don't need either of those helpers. Just reference the variable with an inline JSX expression within the component. Go through the React documentation.

Comment: I tried with formatted text initially but it was not coming up the right way. It was being considered an HTML tag. (I might be doing something wrong there)

Regarding the ques : It would be great if you could provide exact JSX equivalent of the above snippets (atleast for the first one). 
what would be the inline JSX expression for the first above.
 
As per react documentation, class will convert to className, but not sure  about the handlebar helper methods (mainly the above two)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything inside the `unless` block will be rendered if the expression returns a falsy value.

Replace it with the following jsx code:

```
let unless_block = "";
if (!props.quote.def) { unless_block = "&nbsp;" }
return (
    <div className="name">
    { props.abc.def.firstName } { props.abc.def.lastName }
    {unless_block}
    </div>
);
```

Normally, Handlebars templates are evaluated against the context passed into the compiled method.
The `with` helper method is used to shift the context for a section of a template.

Borrowing your example, if your props contain values abc.def.firstName and abc.def.lastName, you can just use firstName and lastName inside a `{{with abc.def}}` block.

There is no variable being used inside your example of a `with`block. That's why I modified your example a bit to show how you can use the abbreviated paymentDescription inside jsx expression. Suppose the paymentDescription was originally burried deep inside `props.abd.def`. Then you can write the following jsx code:

```
let paymentDescription = props.abc.def.paymentDescription; //shift the context

return (
    <div>
    <div className="test">
    {paymentDescription}
    </div>
    </div>
);
```